# Deleting node from linked list doesn't work properly

Tags: c, linked-list

I have one problem while trying to delete a node from a linked list in C.
I totally have no idea where i am missing this, but somehow, wrong nodes are deleted than the expected ones, also the last one is gone and when i do free() it is actually not working, it still keeps and prints some data. 
Can anyone please help me?
Here is my code:

```
node=head;
temp=node->next;

if(record == 1){
    head=head->next;
    printf("\nInside if count %d node %s head %s",count, node->name, head->name);
    free(node);
}
else if (record > 1){
    while(count < record-1 && count < list_size){
        printf("\nInside while count %d node %s head %s",count, node->name, head->name);
        node = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
        node->next = temp->next;
        count++;
    }
    printf("\nOutside while temp %s node %s head %s",temp->name,node->name,head->name);
    free(temp);
}
```

Comment: At least this statement temp=node->next; does not make sense and can result in undefined behavior.

Comment: And show the full function if it is a code snippet from a function.

Comment: This statement node->next = temp->next; in the while loop also does not make sense.

Comment: i am not sure if is allowed to post the full function, but i get the record as a parameter. Why this statement cannot work?

Comment: @user9091498.: You are trying to deleted the record having number `record` ? (starting From `0`)

Comment: @user9091498  Who does not allow you to show your ingenious function?

Comment: record can start from 1

Comment: not sure why i cant post the function.. there is a characters limit or something.. i would prefer to avoid bad comments @VladfromMoscow :)

Comment: @user9091498 Why does the function use global variables?

Comment: @user9091498 I think your question should be closed because it is unclear how the function is declared and defined. For example it is unclear whether the variable head is a global variable or a function parameter and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there are places in your code which may lead to accessing NULL value leading in to invoking Undefined Behavior.

```
node = head;
temp = head;
if( head == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr,"List is empty");
    exit(1);
}
if(record == 1){

    head=head->next;
    printf("\nInside if count %d node %s head %s",count, node->name, head->name);
    free(node);
}
else if (record > 1){
    for(size_t i = 1; i < record && temp != NULL; i++){
       node = temp;
       temp = temp -> next;
    }
    if( temp )
        node->next = temp->next;
    free( temp );
}
```

For writing methods like this, try to use the pointers. Here global variables are not required. Earlier your code had some redundant assignment statements which was not doing anything meaningful.

A full example would be something like

```
struct Node* deleteNth (struct Node *head, int N){
    struct Node *t ;
    if(head == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "List is empty");
        exit(1);
    }
    if( N <= 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Position given wrong");
        exit(1);
    }
    if( N == 1){
        t = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(t);
        return head;
    }

    struct Node *p = t;
    int i;

    for(i = 1; i < N && t!=NULL; i++){
        p = t;
        t = t->next;
    }
    if( t == NULL ){
        fprintf(stderr,"%s\n","Insuffiecient Number of elements" );
        exit(1);
    }
    if( t!= NULL ){
        p->next = t->next;
    }
    free(t);
    return head;
}
```